# MongooseJS cant disable unique to field

Tags: mongoose

This is my mongoosejs schema. I set name unique to false, but this is what i get: **MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: testdb1.images.$name_1  dup key: { : "aaa" }**

```
imageSchema = new Schema({
    url: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },

    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    vote: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
        required: true
    },

    voteArray: [],
    favorite: false,
    tags: []

});
```

any ides how to solve this ? suggestions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mongoose won't modify existing indexes, so you'll need to drop that index in the MongoDB shell and then let Mongoose recreate it using the definition in your schema:

```
> db.images.dropIndex('name_1');
```

Answer (score 9):

Go to the DB(MongoDB)--> Collections --> Your_Table --> Indexes --> Right Click on the Unique Field --> Exit Index --> Uncheck the Unique field --> Save

[image: illustration pic]

Answer (score 0):

**MongoDB Compass**

If you are using MongoDB Compass then you can choose your document and then click on `Indexes` and delete the index which you want to delete.

[image]