# MongoDB gives duplicated error when I use the same name that is unique: false

Tags: mongodb, unique

I try to save and update an entry with upsert, checking the *unicity* *(is that the word? uniqueness?)*, of my own id key, called id. However, when I create a new entry, with a new id, if I write the same name for the object, the error happens:

> errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection:
> app.ticket index: nombre_1 dup key: { nombre: "James
> Bond" }',   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}

The controller looks like this:

```
exports.guardarParte = (req,res,next) =>{
  
    const newParte = {
        id: req.body.id,
        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        telefono:  req.body.telefono,
        ref: req.body.ref,
        marca: req.body.marca,
        fecha: req.body.fecha,
        averia: req.body.averia 
    }
   
    parte.updateOne({id:newParte.id},{$set:newParte}, {upsert:true}, (err,parte)=>{
        if(err && err.code === 11000){
            return res.status(409).send("El parte ya existe(?)"+err);
        }
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).send("No se ha podido crear el parte");
        }
            res.send(parte);
    })
}
```

The model looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex',true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology',true);

const reparacionSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true,
        unique: false
    },
    telefono: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        trim: false
    },
    ref: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: false
    },
    marca: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: false
    },
    fecha: {
        type: Date,
        required: false,
        trim: false
    },
    averia: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: false
    },
},{
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = reparacionSchema;
```

As you see in the model, nombre is set as `unique:false`. knowing this, I don't get why the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongooseJS cant disable unique to field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695676/mongoosejs-cant-disable-unique-to-field)

Comment: Indeed, unchecked Unique in that field, and worked. Thank you!!